# performing function in for loop help? python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Hello everyone I'm in the final step of my program to send in calendar but I can't seem to get my for loop to perform the function over the list. It only reads for 1 of the 3 in list. Here is my code below.

```
Order List = ['0730049','4291200','1830470']

for eachId in Order_List:
**Code to create orders into excel sheet.**

df_list = [f'OrderId_{eachId}.xlsx']
print(df_list)
***everything works fine up until here ***      
for eachOrder in df_list:
  df = pd.read_excel (eachOrder,engine='openpyxl')
  New_Order_Date= df.iat[0,3]
  Order_obj_date= datetime.strptime(New_Order_Date,'%m/%d/%Y').date()
  print(Order_obj_date)
```

my df_list when I print shows me my list of .xlsx files created
output :

```
'0730049.xlsx','4291200.xlsx','1830470.xlsx'
```

But now I need the New_Order_Date to read in each excel file properly and find the date which is at cell value (D,2). Currently, my formula for one excel file, the df. iat[0,3] works perfectly. How can I get it to perform that same search for each of the df_list?

hopefully, this makes sense? but the current code that works for 1 file when printed to give everyone an idea equals:

```
New_Order_Date=df.iat[0,3]
output: 07-01-2022
```

expected output;

```
0730049.xlsx= 07-01-2022
4291200.xlsx= 07-04-2022
1830470.xlsx= 07-27-2022
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. And use `#` comments rather than `**` text for your commentary about it.

Comment: Why is `df_list` a list if it always has just one element?

Comment: its not df_list is `'0730049.xlsx','4291200.xlsx','1830470.xlsx'`
but I wrote it like that so I didnt manual have to add the order excels.

Comment: these are going to be changing based on when the orders are created and printed to excel. so it wont be the same everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df_list` isn't a list of all the filenames. You're overwriting it with just one filename each time through the loop.

Use a list comprehension to get all of them.

```
df_list = [f'OrderId_{eachId}.xlsx' for eachId in Order_List]
```

But you may not even need that variable, just do everything in the loop over `Order_List`

```
for eachId in Order_List:
    df = pd.read_excel (f'OrderId_{eachId}.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
    New_Order_Date= df.iat[0,3]
    Order_obj_date= datetime.strptime(New_Order_Date,'%m/%d/%Y').date()
    print(Order_obj_date)
```